# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id' error after remote database deploy

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've deployed a SQL Server Express 2008 database to my hosting server. On my local machine everything works fine, but on the remote host I'm getting an error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table
>   'mttrnv_12.dbo.Customer'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Table structure:

```
Id  int Unchecked
CustomerGuid    uniqueidentifier    Unchecked
Username    nvarchar(1000)  Checked
Email   nvarchar(1000)  Checked
Password    nvarchar(MAX)   Checked
PasswordFormatId    int Unchecked
PasswordSalt    nvarchar(MAX)   Checked
AdminComment    nvarchar(MAX)   Checked
LanguageId  int Checked
CurrencyId  int Checked
TaxDisplayTypeId    int Unchecked
IsTaxExempt bit Unchecked
VatNumber   nvarchar(MAX)   Checked
VatNumberStatusId   int Unchecked
SelectedPaymentMethodSystemName nvarchar(MAX)   Checked
CheckoutAttributes  nvarchar(MAX)   Checked
DiscountCouponCode  nvarchar(MAX)   Checked
GiftCardCouponCodes nvarchar(MAX)   Checked
UseRewardPointsDuringCheckout   bit Unchecked
TimeZoneId  nvarchar(MAX)   Checked
AffiliateId int Checked
Active  bit Unchecked
Deleted bit Unchecked
IsSystemAccount bit Unchecked
SystemName  nvarchar(MAX)   Checked
LastIpAddress   nvarchar(MAX)   Checked
CreatedOnUtc    datetime    Unchecked
LastLoginDateUtc    datetime    Checked
LastActivityDateUtc datetime    Unchecked
BillingAddress_Id   int Checked
ShippingAddress_Id  int Checked
        Unchecked
```

Comment: Please check if the column is still marked as an `IDENTITY` column on the remote server. Also if you want specific help please tell us the structure of the table and the insert query you're trying to send.

Comment: We don't need the stack dump. Just details about the table structure and the insert statement you're attempting.

Comment: About insert statement i'm not sure, because i'm using a tool called "NopCommerce" and a database that i'm trying to deploy is the base that was create when i'm install "NopCommerce" on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

On the remote host, your `Id` column does not allow `NULL` values.

You should double-check that the remote host is using the same schema as the local one. It is not.

Comment: How to do this using MSSQL Server Managment Studio?

Comment: Same schema (on local and on host) - "dbo", looked in a properties of a table.

Comment: @mttrnv: I've got a suspicion that by *‘the same schema’* Borealid did **not** mean the same schema *name*, but rather the same schema *definition*, i.e. column types, constraints etc., including `NULL/NOT NULL` properties, of the local schema (local tables) should match those on the remote side.

Comment: Schema perfectly matched( I don't understand how that possible if on local machine all works fine, but after just copying on remote host same files and export database through MSSQL Server Management Studio and simple connection database to site gives that result. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: @mttrnv If the tables are identical in both places, then the difference must be in the application behavior. Why would your code try to insert a `NULL` on the remote end, but not the local one?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe try to change a hosting?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in MSSQL 2008 export dialog (read [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1546696.aspx/1/10)). Mainly, not full set of data copy on remote host (another database). To resolve this problem i use great free utility called SQL Tools, you can download it [here](http://www.simego.com/Products/SQL-Admin-Studio). What it does - compare your local and remote databases. When differences detected the programm automatically synchronize databases to achive 100% match. Thats it!